# Need help building complex JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to construct an array in JavaScript, but I'm not sure of the correct way to do it, or if this type of array is even possible...

Lets say I have a key for each item in the array starting with 'a' and ending with 'z'. For each item, the array key will correspond with another multidimensional array. These new multidimensional arrays are a series of coordinates (x and y). Each item in the original array can have many sets of coordinates. For example:

[image]

How can I construct such an array with Javascript? What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the data you've provided:

```
var arr = {
  a: [[20,15],[25,17],[10,45]],
  b: [[10,33],[12,2],[14,9],[72,103],[88,12]],
  c: [[2,2],[41,21]],
  d: [[0,0],[21,2],[44,44],[19,99],[1,1],[100,100]],
  e: [[1,1],
  f: [[3,40],[41,86]]
}
```

The first structure you want, a keyed array, isn't an array in JavaScript - it's an object. Objects contain key-value pairs. In this case, the values are arrays, and the objects in those arrays are themselves arrays.

An important thing to note here if you're coming from another language that defines 'regular' multi-dimensional arrays is that there is no expectation or guarantee that the 'rows' of this structure are all the same length.

Comment: that's an object ... not an array

Comment: Correct. The OP asked for an 'array' keyed 'a', 'b', 'c'...etc. In some languages, that would be an array. In Javascript, it's not. I think delivering the behavior the OP wants is more important than adhering to the words they used, when they appear to be fairly new to the language.

Comment: S McCrohan is correct, this is the behavior that I'm looking for and I'm glad you were able to understand what I meant.

Comment: @SMcCrohan, how do I now reference one of the values from c?

Comment: arr.c[0][1]  is 2; arr.c[1][0] is 41. You can also reference it as arr['c'][0][1] (note the quotes, they're required)  though that's less common and many style checkers will chide you for it. However, also check out James Hay's answer below for an approach with a slightly cleaner set of references.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another possible option to your list, on the same lines as @SMcCrohan's answer, mixing objects and arrays.

```
var coords = {
    a: [{
            x: 20,
            y: 15
        },
        {
            x: 25,
            y: 17
        }],
    b: [{
            x: 10,
            y: 30
        }],

    ....
};
```

This assumes you will always use coordinates `x` and `y`, It means you can access the values like so:

```
var value1 = coords.a[1].x; // 25
var value2 = coords.b[0].y; // 30
```

Comment: Doing it this way, instead of using a tuple array as the inner-most structure, will result in more readable code. `coords.a[2].x` is more immediately readable than `coords.a[2][0]`. (Wish I'd thought of it!)

Comment: But of course a well-written `getCoord` function might be even more readable: `getCoord('a', 2, 'x')`.

Comment: Agreed, Scott. Doing both would be good, though. That way if you ever pull one of the inner structures out (`var coord = coords.a[0]`) you're left with an object that carries some sense of intent with it still.