# How do I create a multi-dimension javascript array from variable.

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I've built this variable called DLP. When I'm done doing what i need to do with the page, the variable looks something like this:

```
[['0','A'],['1','B'],['2','C'] ]
```

How can I turn this variable into a multi-dimension array so that when i go:

DLP[1][1]

it returns my result?

Comment: `DLP[1][1]` *will* return a result, **B**.  What is *your* result that you're expecting it to return?

Comment: I had a similar question to this once. My question and answers may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738068/need-help-building-complex-js-object

Comment: Do you mean that DLP is a string variable with the content as shown? Please clarify.

Comment: Exactly! DLP is a string variable that's put together by doing stuff on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// the data
var dlp = "[['0','A'],['1','B'],['2','C'] ]";

// make it JSON conform
// replace single quotation marks with double quotation marks
dlp = dlp.replace(/'/g, '"');

// parse the JSON string
// get an array
var dlpArray = JSON.parse(dlp);

// use the array
alert(dlpArray[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to start an array.

`var array = new Array();` or `var array = [1, 2, 3]`

It is considered bad practice to do it the first way. You can do what you want like this.

`var DLP = [['0','A'],['1','B'],['2','C'] ]`

`DLP[1][1]` will return your result.

Answer (score 0):

`[['0','A'],['1','B'],['2','C'] ]` is already a multi-dimensional array. 
`DLP[1][1]` will return 'B' as Tom said in the comments. If you want to get one of the complete arrays (example: if you wanted the array: "2,C" you would only need to reference `DLP[3]`). See this question for more information on how to work with multidimensional arrays: [JavaScript multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)